# Page Navigation not working on the final for loop iteration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a Google Form using Apps Script. The form utilises a nested `for-loop` which directs the user to the correct section of the form. However, for the innermost loop, where the user clicks to submit their response, the final iteration of that loop does not provide the option to SUBMIT - it says "continue onto next section".

To give you some context. It is a parents evening appointment system where users first select a teacher and then the day they would like there appointment. The last day in the for loop, is Thursday which is the day that says 'CONTINUE ONTO NEXT SECTION' when it should say 'SUBMIT'.

The form works for every other day prior to the Thursday loop and I'm not sure why.

Wednesday [image]

Thursday [image]

I have indicated the part of code that needs rectifying with asterisks (*)

```
function updateForms() {
  var setUpSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Set-Up')
  var times = setUpSheet.getRange(2, 2, setUpSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues()
  var teacherNames = setUpSheet.getRange(2, 1, setUpSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues()
  Logger.log(teacherNames)

  var appointmentRange = setUpSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues()
  var appointmentRangeCount = appointmentRange.filter(String).length
  var appointmentDays = setUpSheet.getRange(2, 3, appointmentRangeCount, 1).getValues()
  Logger.log(appointmentDays)

// Opening page where user selects the teacher

  var page1 = form.addPageBreakItem()
  page1.setTitle('Parent\'s Evening Appointment System')
  var item = form.addListItem()
  item.setRequired(true)
  var teacherPages = []

  for (var n in teacherNames) {
    var appointmentPages = []
    var teacherName = teacherNames[n]
    Logger.log(teacherName)
    var newPage = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(teacherName)
    teacherPages.push(item.createChoice(teacherName, newPage))
    var item2 = form.addListItem()
    item2.setTitle('Choose Day')
    item2.setRequired(true)
    for (var i in appointmentDays) {
      var appointmentDay = appointmentDays[i]
      Logger.log(appointmentDay)
      var newPage2 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(teacherName + ' ' + appointmentDay)
      appointmentPages.push(item2.createChoice(appointmentDay, newPage2))
      var item3 = form.addListItem()
      item3.setTitle(n + '. Please choose your appointment time. ' + i)
      item3.setRequired(true)
      item3.setChoiceValues(times)
      newPage2.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)*********
    }
    item2.setChoices(appointmentPages)  
  }
  item.setTitle('Select your child\'s teacher.')
  item.setChoices(teacherPages)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Task Complete', 'Status');

}
```

How would I solve this?

Comment: Where does that page point to, if one clicks continue?

Comment: It continues onto the subsequent teachers first day for appointments. That is,  apart from the last teacher in the array in which the last day for them (a Thursday) allows them to SUBMIT the response.

Comment: @tehhowch, thanks for the edits of my post. I am trying to improve how I write the posts. Regarding my issue, are you able to offer any insight into my issue with page navigation?